# How do colour pigments chemically work?

Tags: bond, color, plastics

How do color pigments colour the plastics? Is there any chemical reaction, molecular association, or physical reaction? 
What kind of bonding mechanism is there between pigment molecules and plastics?

How could Polypropylen and liquid organic pigments or granular organic pigments join each other? Pigments dont have oil or any solvent.

What would happen in molecular level?

Comment: It depends on both the substrate and the pigment/dye. Some are purely physical; some involve chemical reactions. You need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromophore?wprov=sfla1

Comment: I guess, this is, chomophore,  more about how the molecules absorb the light. I was wondering the bonding mechanism,  if there is chemical, physical or combined bonding mechanism, between the fluid organic pigments and PP material.